# Whats is correct way to work with PostgreSQL from Python threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql

I need to increase speed of parsing heap of XML files. I decided to try use Python threads, but I do not know how to correct work from them with DB.
My DB store only links to files. I decided to add `isProcessing` column to my DB to prevent acquire of same rows from multiple threads
So result table look like:

`|xml_path|isProcessing|`

Every thread set this flag before starting processing and other threads select for procossings rows where this flags is not set.

But I am not sure that is correct way, because I am not sure that acquire is atomic and two threads my to process same row two times.

```
def select_single_file_for_processing():
    #...
    sql = """UPDATE processing_files SET "isProcessing" = 'TRUE' WHERE "xml_name"='{0}'""".format(xml_name)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()   

def worker():
    result = select_single_file_for_processing() #   
    # ...
    # processing()

def main():
    # ....
    while unprocessed_xml_count != 0: # now unprocessed_xml_count is global! I know that it's wrong, but how to fix it?

        checker_thread = threading.Thread(target=select_total_unpocessed_xml_count)
        checker_thread.start() # if we have files for processing

        for i in range(10): # run processed
            t = Process(target=worker)
            t.start()
```

The second question - what is the best practice to work with DB from `multiprocessing` module?

Answer (score 0):

As written, your `isProcessing` flag could have problems with multiple threads. You should include a predicate for `isProcessing = FALSE` and check how many rows are updated. One thread will report 1 row and any other threads will report 0 rows.

As to best practices? This is a reasonable solution. The key is to be specific. A simple update will set the values as specified. The operation you are trying to perform though is to change the value from a to b, hence including the predicate for a in the statement.

```
UPDATE processing_files
SET isProcessing = 'TRUE'
WHERE xmlName = '...'
AND isProcessing = 'FALSE';
```